# How to stop apps opening up on all users? (IMac M1 - Ventura)

Tags: macos, profile-manager

I am the admin user on the Mac. My sister was logged into her account (it has a password that idk) and I ended up using it while it was logged into her account.

I stepped away from the computer and it locked me out and now I can’t get back into her profile. Im currently in the middle of planning a surprise for her and I had left all my tabs open.

Whenever I log into the Mac it always brings up whatever tabs and applications I had open. **Is there any way at all I can close her tabs out from my end so it doesn’t open when she logs in?** I obviously don’t want to reset her password as that will tip her off.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not a perfect Get Out of Jail Free card.*

History will remain. I don't know of a way to selectively remove items from it by digging inside the database files. What it will do is make Safari restart empty when next launched.
So, if your sister just invokes 'Restore all windows from last session' they'll all come back. Clearing all her History would be a dead giveaway, and also rather socially unacceptable, no matter the good intent ;)

From *your* Finder,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>  Go To… `/Users/[other_name]/`

Select the Library folder - it will show as locked - and Get Info.
It may be best to view all this in column view  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>  as it will make later trackback easier.

Click the lock, then press  <kbd>+</kbd>  and add yourself as Read & Write. this will now let you into that folder.

Further down you'll see Containers, then com.apple.safari, then Data, Library, Saved Application State, com.apple.Safari.SavedState [these may again be locked, so repeat the above procedure.] Each time you do this you have to select another folder, then the unlocked one again for it to show you the contents.
Leave all these Info windows open so you can tidy up afterwards.

Once inside here, delete the files inside the folder [not the folder itself]

To be tidy, once you've done this, go back up those folders in reverse order & remove your privileges.

Then reboot the Mac, using your admin credentials to override the Restart warning.

Her Safari, next time she logs in, will be a single default page.

You didn't actually say which browser, so I assumed Safari. If it was Chrome, the path is much simpler - `Users/[other_name]/Library/Saved Application State/com.Google.Chrome.savedState`

In case anyone was wondering why I didn't go to Safari's saved state by the simpler path - Safari's saved state folder is actually an alias, which you cannot access on *someone else's account* without unlocking the path to it first. I didn't want to just change perms right down the hierarchy in a non-reversible manner or one that needs Terminal to restore.